# How to remove site path from webpage share point online using 0365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-directory

How do remove the site path/directory from a SharePoint online site that was built using office365?

It is posted at the time of the page looks like /sites/homepage

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to delete the homepage?